# APT-GET behind a proxy with DIGEST Authentication

Tags: apt, proxy, authentication

I've edited `apt.conf`, applied "system wide configuration", edited `/etc/enviroment`, etc... but out of luck.

My company is running a Squid proxy with **DIGEST authentication**, which I think APT doesn't support.

Has anyone faced this issue?

- `apt.conf`:

  ```
  Acquire::http::proxy "http://[user]:[password]@[host]:[port]/";
  Acquire::https::proxy "https://[user]:[password]@[host]:[port]/";
  ```
- enviroment:

  ```
  http_proxy="http://[user]:[password]@[host]:[port]/"
  https_proxy="https://[user]:[password]@[host]:[port]/"
  ```

I always get "407 Authentication Required".

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem, my university use a proxy with digest authentication.
The only way around I have found so far is to use a tool like redsocks which can authenticate with your digest proxy, then you redirect your traffic (ex. with iptables) to the redsocks proxy which don't need authentication.

## Step 1: Install redsocks

```
sudo apt install redsocks
```

but since you can't use apt in your company you will need to download the `.deb` file and install it using `sudo apt deb xxxxx.deb`

## Step 2: Configure redsocks to use your proxy

Edit `/etc/redsocks.conf` and replace the following parameters in the `redsocks` section:

```
redsocks { 
...
ip = <YOUR-PROXY-IP>;   // example: 10.12.1.77                                                          
port = <YOUR-PROXY-PORT>;  // example: 3128
...
type = <YOUR-PROXY-TYPE>; // example: http-connect
...
login = <YOUR-USERNAME>;   // the username for your proxy                                                      
password = <YOUR-PASWORD>;  // the password for your proxy
}
```

## Step 3: Restart redsocks service to update configuration

```
sudo service redsocks restart
```

## Step 4: Configure iptables

Save the following to a shell script so you don't have to type it every time:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                             
if [ -z $SUDO_COMMAND ]; then                                                        
    sudo $0 $*                                                                       
    exit 0                                                                           
fi                                                                                   

## Create new chain                                                                  
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS                                                          

## Ignore LANs and some other reserved addresses.                                    
## See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#Reserved_IPv4_addresses    
## and http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735 for full list of reserved networks.        
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN                                   
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN                                  
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN                                 
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN                              
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN                               
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN                              
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN                                 
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN                                 

## Anything else should be redirected to port 12345                                  
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345  

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDSOCKS
```

execute the above script so the iptable rules are created.

## Step 5: Have fun

Just start using `apt-get`

> See http://www.darkk.net.ru/redsocks/ or the redsock manual for more information.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: thanks for the recommendation,  wow people are fast giving down votes, hahaha XD anyway I don't care, what I want is to help other people so they don't feel so struggled as I did

Comment: +1 already! :-)  Much better...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and I would completely understand that this feature is just not supported.

Indeed, Digest authentication is [quite weak from the security perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication#Disadvantages):

- From the client point of view it does nothing to prevent several range of attacks like Man-In-The-Middle attacks,
- From the server perspective it is even worse since it makes it impossible to store passwords in a secure way, using strong password hashes.

Digest authentication impairs usability without concretely increasing security.

Therefore, nowadays, there is very little to no use for this protocol:

- Either security matters, then use Basic authentication secured by an HTTPS connection between the client and the proxy,
- Or if security does not matter, then Basic authentication over a plain HTTP is acceptable.